# Finding difference between 2 tables in MS Access or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access

I have 2 Excel files which I imported into MS Access as two tables. These two tables are identical but imported on different dates.

Now, how can I find out what rows and what fields are updated on the later date? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide schema of those tables ?

Comment: Assuming they have a common "ID" field, join them on that field, and add a WHERE clause where the UpdatedDate is different.

Comment: Or, if you don't have UpdatedDate kind of field, then you have to compare all fields one by one. If you even don't have ID (or any other unique, like Code, EAN etc) field, then you first need to write down, what and how you need to compare - after that select will be easy to write :)

Comment: @Arvo I dont have any unique identifier of the tables. So, May I get an example please?

Comment: I said - write down, what [fields or field combinations] and how [what you consider equal, what not and what makes your table rows unique] you need to compare. You can't do things, about what you have no understanding, do you?

Comment: I'm just curious . . . if you unaccepted my answer, could you leave a comment explaining why?

Answer (score 1):

Finding Inserted records is easy

```
select * from B where not exists (select 1 from A where A.pk=B.pk)
```

Finding Deleted records is just as easy

```
select * from A where not exists (select 1 from B where A.pk=B.pk)
```

Finding Updated records is a pain. The following rigorous query assumes you have nullable columns and it should work in all situations.

```
select B.*
  from B
  inner join A on B.pk=A.pk
 where A.col1<>B.col1 or (IsNull(A.col1) and not IsNull(B.col1)) or (not IsNull(A.col1) and  IsNull(B.col1))
    or A.col2<>B.col2 or (IsNull(A.col2) and not IsNull(B.col2)) or (not IsNull(A.col2) and  IsNull(B.col2))
    or A.col3<>B.col3 or (IsNull(A.col3) and not IsNull(B.col3)) or (not IsNull(A.col3) and  IsNull(B.col3))
    etc...
```

If the columns are defined as NOT NULL then the query is much simper, just remove all the NULL tests.

If the columns are nullable but you can identify a value that will never appear in the data, then use a simple comparison like:

```
Nz(A.col1,neverAppearingValue)<>Nz(B.col1,neverAppearingValue)
```

Comment: I don't have any primary key for the tables, Could you please show me an example for the same please?

Comment: You may not have defined the PK for your tables, but hopefully you have a logical key in there somewhere. It could be a multi-part key, in which case of course the join ON clause needs to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be as simple as running a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
    JOIN Table2
         ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND Table1.Date != Table2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by unpivoting both tables, so you get a new table with , , .  Note, though, that you have to take types into account.

For example, the following gets differences in fields:

```
with oldt as (select id, col, val
              from <old table> t
              unpivot (val for col in (<column list>)) unpvt
             ),
     newt as (select id, col, val
              from <new table> t
              unpivot (val for col in (<column list>)) unpvit
             )
select *
from oldt full outer join newt on oldt.id = newt.id
where oldt.id is null or newt.id is null
```

The alternative way with a join is rather cumbersome.  This version shows whether columns are added, deleted, and which columns changed if any:

```
select *
from (select coalesce(oldt.id, newt.id) as id,
             (case when oldt.id is null and newt.id is not null then 'ADDED'
                   when oldt.id is not null and newt.id is null then 'DELETED'
                   else 'SAME'
              end) as stat,
             (case when oldt.col1 <> newt.col1 or oldt.col1 is null and newt.col1 is null
                   then 1 else 0 end) as diff_col1,
             (case when oldt.col2 <> newt.col2 or oldt.col2 is null and newt.col2 is null
                   then 1 else 0 end) as diff_col2,
             ...
      from <old table> oldt full outer join <new table> newt on oldt.id = newt.id
     ) c
where status in ('ADDED', 'DELETED') or
     (diff_col1 + diff_col2 + ... ) > 0
```

It does have the advantage of working for any data types.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Select * from OldTable Except Select *from NewTable)
Union All
(Select * from NewTable Except Select *from OldTable)
```